# Display a List based off another subsite's list

Tags: list-view

is this possible? I wanted to load a webpart that calls a list based off another department's(which is a subsite) list..

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Content Query Web Part` to show a list from another site as the following

- Open your Page > Click on Add web Part > below Content Rollup > Add Content Query Web Part .
- Click to open the tool pane to edit
- At Query section > at Show items from the following list: > click browse to `browse any list from any site below your site collection`.
- Select the list that you need from the subsite.
- In presentation section, select the item style that you need to show the list item.

[image]

Foe more details to configure CQWP check [Display a dynamic view of content on a page by adding the Content Query Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-dynamic-view-of-content-on-a-page-by-adding-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-3e35bd58-d159-43d6-bfc7-77878b4a856d)

Comment: I'm planning to project an image from a list, is that possible via CQWP?

Comment: yes it's possible via CQWP based on your selected item style, the first CQWP will provide you to get this list from a subsite as you request in your question , the second yu can customize the retrieved items to show it in custom style, the third option you can sort and filter your retrieved value  refer to the attached link from Microsoft to know more about its capability, it is the easiest out of the box solution that you can use to get data from other list in other sites

Comment: Meanwhile, if you need to show list as list view via CQWP check https://msftplayground.com/2011/01/sharepoint-content-query-web-part-like-a-sharepoint-list-view/ please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification

Comment: I could not add any other fields, it only has  my title field showing in the resulting CQWP? Is there an easier way to add more fields?